# Are deleted SMS still retrievable from Android-based phones?

Tags: android, sms

I'm wondering whether deleted SMS on Android phones are retrievable?
If so, how is this done? How can one avoid it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad because each manufacturer provides their own SMS messaging program.  To answer for each would be quite an undertaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is retrievable if it's not overwritten.  On solid-state devices like our phones we need to be careful to start from an encrypted starting point to avoid some of the theoretical recovery ([ForensicsWiki](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Solid_State_Drive_%28SSD%29_Forensics)).

Short answer, Oxygen is something I've used to pull data off phones, but all it really requires is physical access, take a physical image, and use forensics tools like FTK or EnCase to look through hex a little easier.  Better yet, use Oxygen to make the everything pretty and organized (http://www.oxygen-forensic.com).

Short short answer, you need to overwrite your data / encrypt the data to avoid recoverability.  Even then I'm sure some wizards could get bits and pieces given enough time.

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, they can not be retrieved by 'bare hand'. using only the phone itself. correct?

Comment: I'm not aware of any native (android) forensics tools that would be able to do that.